# Clear a file without changing its timestamp

Tags: linux, file, timestamp

Is it possible to clear a file preserving its timestamp, using standard Linux commands? For example:

echo "" > file-name

converts the text file to empty, this is OK for me. But I need to keep the timestamp unchanged.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do the following using touch:

```
#!/bin/sh
TMPFILE=`mktemp`
#save the timestamp
touch -r file-name $TMPFILE
> file_name
#restore the timestamp after truncation
touch -r $TMPFILE file-name
rm $TMPFILE
```

Answer (score 3):

You can skip the tmp file by using date to record the time stamp string and pass it back to touch.

```
#!/bin/sh
# Save the timestamp
STAMP=`date -r file_name`
> file_name
# Restore the timestamp
touch -d "$STAMP" file_name
```

Comment: While I still think this it's cleaner and faster not to write to the file system, the -r flag is not as pervasive as I thought.  For example OSX Lion's Darwin shell does not support it.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://unstableme.blogspot.com/2009/02/linux-copy-file-and-preserve-timestamp.html) is the nice article. Hope it help.

**ADDED:**

Sorry, just read, that you need the zero file, not the copy. **Touch** could create zero files with needed time stamps.

Example

```
   To set the date to 7:30 am 1st October 2015
   touch /t 2015 10 01 07 30 00 MyFile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

To supplement **mmond**'s answer (can't comment due to insufficient reputation), don't forget about localization. To work with any localization, the answer should read:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Save the timestamp
STAMP=`LANG= date -r file_name`
> file_name
# Restore the timestamp
touch -d "$STAMP" file_name
```